# Form not submitted using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have following form,

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" id="offer1Form">
    <input type="hidden" name="c" value="3883316">
    <input type="hidden" name="qtyadd" id="qtyadd" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="buyid" id="buyid" value="multi">
    <input type="hidden" name="multi" id="multi" value="11,1;150,1;182,1;27,1; ">
    <input type="hidden" name="promocode" value="<?php echo $promote_code1?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="continue" value="<?php echo " http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] "; ?>" />
    <map name="map">
        <area id="offer1" shape="rect" coords="657, 515, 913, 557" href="" />
    </map>
</form>
```

and I'm trying submit this using following jquery code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#offer1").click(function() {
        $("#offer1Form").submit();
        //document.getElementById("offer1Form").submit();
        alert('something');
    });
});
```

alert displayed, but form is not submitted. Please tell me the reason about this issue.

Comment: what about `document.getElementById("offer1Form").submit();`

Comment: One possibe reason is there is a submit event handler which is called `preventDefault()`

Comment: You won't see `alert` because `form` is submitted and page is redirected

Comment: No alert is displayed but page is just refreshed after showing alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me.
you can check with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#offer1").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#offer1Form").submit();
        //document.getElementById("offer1Form").submit();
        alert('something');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to see the `alert` use below code and try.

```
$( "#offer1Form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert('something');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```